# "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular"

Tags: angular, npm, terminal, homebrew, node-modules

I have deleted npm and node. In addition, I have deleted and restored homebrew. I downloaded npm and node from the online download site to restore them. I also downloaded the angular cli through npm. I located my desktop through the terminal and typed

```
ng new mag-board
```

to begin my angular project. I was prompted with the following error:

```
Schematic "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
Error: Schematic "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:232:23)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:69:29)
    at NewCommand.getSchematic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:130:27)
    at NewCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:43:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I Deleted npm,
Deleted node, and I
Deleted Angular CLI

I reinstalled npm, node, and Angular CLI

I should be able to generate an Angular project from typing ng new mag-board

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the answer in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10862

I'll short it for you:

**first option:**

```
sudo npm uninstall @schematics/angular
```

and

```
sudo npm i @schematics/angular
```

**if it's not wroking, then:**

Remove the node_modules folder in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in angular Command prompt  :

- **npm install @schematics/angular updated**
- if this doesn't work try uninstall and install @angula/cli.
  Here's the command for installing and uninstalling angular-cli
- **npm uninstall @angular/cli**
- **npm install @angular/cli**

then use this command in your angular prompt:

**npm install @schematics/angular updated**